# If the command "write" is typed in a text box and it contains "^n" then print off the words after it on the next line of the second textbox

Tags: c#

I am creating a "Programming Language" for a friend of mine and he wanted the "print" command or in this case "write" so I made it but he also wanted it to check for a "^n" which will mean "next line" but I don't know how to do that
I am using two text boxes
Here is the code that reads the first textbox for commands:

```
string[] text = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            if (line.Contains("write") || line.Contains("WRITE"))
            {
                textBox2.Text = line.Substring(6);
                if (line.Substring(6) == "^n")
                {
                    //Print words after the "^n" to the next line
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't know how I can print off to the second line
BTW:
textBox1 is the TextBox the commands for the language are type
the the user presses the run button and then it reads for the commands
and if the command on a line is "write" then put what I typed after "write" into textBox2

I hope I made that clear enough for you to understand

Comment: Try making the `textbox2` `Multiline` property enabled from properties and replace the  ^n with `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: You already know Split(), split on "^n" instead.  If you get more than one element back then Join() with "\r\n".

Comment: line.ToLower().Contains("write") <- you only need one check that way and if your friend for example wrote 'WrItE' it still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `textBox2.Multiline=true` to make the second TextBox multiline.  Then use `textBox2.Text = line.Substring(6).Replace("^n", Environment.NewLine)` to set the text.

Comment: Ok, I updated the multiline part for Windows Forms instead of WPF.